# Research and development data before 1970 for United States

Tags: research, economic-history

I'm looking for expenditure of research and development data per sector or averaged across all sectors from the United States prior to 1970 either in absolute values or in percentage of GDP.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you are looking for and why?

Comment: I need the data for a master thesis about patent law..

Comment: https://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=GERD_FUNDS_PRE1981 and https://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=RD_ACTIVITY_PRE1981 have some numbers for the United States back to 1963